# Are gambits a good way to improve tactical awareness (for strong amateurs)?

Tags: opening, learning, gambits, attack

As gambits are all about activity, initiative, and attack, should I start playing gambits to increase my awareness and all these things?

Comment: It is one way to get positions with more tactical potential, where you can train your tactical abilities (which also include setting up tactics, not only spotting them). But gambits are not the only way to achieve these positions, many of the sharpest openings out there are in fact not gambits. To sum up: You can, but you don't have to play gambits to improve the tactical potential of your games.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is a "strong amateur"? 1600? 2000? 2400?

Comment: I think about 1500??

Comment: strong amateur should be a little bit weaker than a weak professional right? So perhaps CM to FM type ratings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! Playing a highly tactical position that you aren't used to can help you train your tactics, but there are plenty of non-gambit alternatives that are also rich in tactics (think for instance of most lines in the Sicilian defense)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A direct open tactical style of play is the fastest route to chess mastery. Look at the games of Morphy. It allows to commit faster mistakes, therefore faster learning. Play dangerously